# Parse in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, heroku, parse-platform

I have downloaded the parse starter project from their website
https://parse.com/docs/downloads
and setup server on heroku but when i try to run the app it simply crashes. All the config variables are correct have verified them thoroughly. Here's the code which is totally fine and is the default code (i'm running android studio v1.5.1)

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .applicationId("instagram2EGB")
                    .clientKey("eugf236x")
                    .server("https://instagram2149.herokuapp.com/parse/")
                    .build()
    );

    ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
    gameScore.put("score", 1337);
    gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
    gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
    gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
        } else {
          Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
        }
      }
    });


    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this);

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

and here is the error [Error shown while running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU8iP.png)

Comment: Parse has been shut down. Opt for another alternatives

Comment: What are the other alternatives of parse

Comment: @salihkallai If you've setup a server on Heroku you''ll be fine - you're not depending on the Parse service (closing jan. 2017) but on the open source Parse-Server project.

Comment: Your line numbering doesn't really match your stack trace, and I know nothing about Parse, but you're calling `Parse.initialize()` twice.

Comment: Lovely @MikeM. Such a simple mistake. Yeah the code runs now!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .applicationId("instagram2EGB")
                    .clientKey("eugf236x")
                    .server("https://instagram2149.herokuapp.com/parse")
                    .build()
    );

    ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
    gameScore.put("score", 1337);
    gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
    gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
    gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
      public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          Log.i("Parse", "Save Succeeded");
        } else {
          Log.i("Parse", "Save Failed");
        }
      }
    });


    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```